# Displaying a PDF in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm not looking to generate a pdf, I just want it to display normally using the browser. I'm using Rails, but in production I get a missing template error, and in development I get "Failed to Load" error. The PDF is in my public folder. I don't understand why homepage.com/my_pdf.pdf doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the log file from your server which may help diagnose the problem

Comment: https://gyazo.com/90aeb8360dac242e7cce314d49eac5cb here's a screenshot of the error.